# Show that the factor ring $R[x]/(1−ax)$ is a zero ring, that is, $R[x]/(1−ax)=\{(1−ax)\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and let $a\in R$ such that $a^{(n−1)}$ is not zero, but $a^n$ is zero for some positive integer $n$. Show that the factor ring $R[x]/(1−ax)$ is a zero ring, that is,
$$
R[x]/(1−ax)=\{(1−ax)\}
$$
I tried:
let $b\in(1−ax)$, then $b=(1-ax)c=c-cax$ for some $c\in R$. Since $a^n$ is zero and $a^{(n-1)}$ is not zero, $a$ is a zero divisor. then
$$
(b+(1-ax))^n=b^n+(1-ax)
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

Saying that $A/I$ is a zero ring, when $A$ is a ring with identity and $I$ is an ideal thereof, means that $I=A$.

In order to prove $(1-ax)=R[x]$, you just need to show that $1\in(1-ax)$, so you need to find an inverse of $1-ax$.

Now, if you were dealing with series in calculus, you'd write
$$
\frac{1}{1-ax}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^kx^k
$$

Can you make a guess now?